# Swift mapping/filtering by dynamic class?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to filter an array of objects by type of its variables. Node is an object which have a position, but defined in different ways — as a Point, Vector or Attachment. This is a code:

```
class Joint {
    var position:Position
    init(_ position:Position) {
        self.position = position
    }
}

class Position {
    var point:Point {
        return Point (0,0)
    }
}

class Point: Position {
   //Something different 
}

class Vector:Position {
   //Something different 
}

class Attachment : Position {
   //Something different 
}

let content : [Joint] = [Joint(Vector()), Joint(Vector()), Joint(Attachment()), Joint(Point()), Joint(Point()) ]
let positionTypes:[Position.Type] = [Point.self, Attachment.self, Vector.self]


let points :[Position] = content.filter{$0.position is Point}.map{$0.position as! Point}
Swift.print(points)
    // OK, prints: [__lldb_expr_148.Point, __lldb_expr_148.Point]
let attachments :[Position] = content.filter{$0.position is Attachment}.map{$0.position as! Attachment}
Swift.print(attachments)
    // OK, prints: [__lldb_expr_148.Attachment]
let vectors :[Position] = content.filter{$0.position is Vector}.map{$0.position as! Vector}
Swift.print(vectors)
    // OK, prints: [__lldb_expr_148.Vector, __lldb_expr_148.Vector]

for positionType in positionTypes {
    Swift.print (positionType, type(of:positionType))

    //  if the next line does not exist loop returns:
    //        Point Position.Type
    //        Attachment Position.Type
    //        Vector Position.Type

    //  This line doesn't work:
    let positions:[Position] = content.filter{$0.position is positionType}.map{$0.position as! positionType}
}
```

On the last line I have a message `Use of undeclared type positionType`.

How to get last line working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right approach:

```
let points :[Position] = content.filter{$0.position is Point}.map{$0.position as! Point}
```

The right tool here is `flatMap`:

```
let points: [Position] = content.flatMap { $0.position as? Point }
```

But `as?` casting isn't really necessary. `.position` is always a `Position`; there's no need to cast it to anything. So you could also do it this way:

```
let points: [Position] = content.map { $0.position }.filter { $0 is Point }
```

That pattern allows you to do what you're trying to do in the last step. Map to `.position` and then filter on type.

```
let positions:[Position] = content
    .map { $0.position }
    .filter { type(of: $0) == positionType }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course! Totally agree with You. (Too much juggling). Why in this case 'positionType' is <declared Type>? How?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "`positionType' is <declared Type>." positionType is a variable of type Position.Type. Its value is a type. `type(of:)` also returns a type.

Comment: I didn't knew what interpunction I should use for <declared type>. I had en error 'Use of undeclared type positionType' at last line. And now it magically became declared. In a line "content.filter{$0.position is positionType}..." position Type was not variable of any type, it was "undeclared".

Comment: `positionType` is a variable that contains a type. It is not a type itself. `is` and `as!` require a literal type. So `is Position` is legal because there is a type called "Position," but `is positionType` is not since there is no type with the name "positionType" (there's a variable of that name, not a type). `type(of:)` is a function that accepts a type *value* rather than the name of a type.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can go ahead down this route, have you considered using an `enum`? Since you want to represent multiple types of data inside of an array.

e.g.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

protocol Position {
    var point: Point { get }
}

enum PositionType {
    case point
    case vector
    case attachment
}

enum Joint {

    case point(Point)
    case vector(Vector)
    case attachment(Attachment)

    var position: Position {
        switch self {
        case .point(let position):
            return position
        case .vector(let position):
            return position
        case .attachment(let position):
            return position
        }
    }

    var positionType: PositionType {
        switch self {
        case .point:
            return .point
        case .vector:
            return .vector
        case .attachment:
            return .attachment
        }
    }

    func isPositionType(_ positionType: PositionType) -> Bool {
        return self.positionType == positionType
    }

}

class Point: Position {
    var point: Point { return self }
}

class Vector:Position {
    var point: Point { return Point() }
}

class Attachment : Position {
    var point: Point { return Point() }
}

let content: [Joint] = [.vector(Vector()), .vector(Vector()), .attachment(Attachment()), .point(Point()), .point(Point()) ]

// for-in syntax

for case .point(let point) in content {
    print("Point", point)
}

for case .vector(let vector) in content {
    print("Vector", vector)
}

for case .attachment(let attachment) in content {
    print("Attachment", attachment)
}

// using PositionType to filter

let positionTypes: [PositionType] = [ .point, .vector, .attachment ]

for positionType in positionTypes {
    let positions = content.filter { $0.isPositionType(positionType) }
}

// using filter

let points = content.filter {
    $0.positionType == .point
}

let vectors = content.filter {
    $0.positionType == .vector
}

let attachments = content.filter {
    $0.positionType == .attachment
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it's more elegant. But in my real life all classes — Joint, Position, Point etc... are NSManagedObject subclasses.

Comment: You could always convert them into these data types, then you don't have to muddy the callsite whenever you use them